# How to invert (transpose) the rows and columns of an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to transpose the rows and columns in an HTML table, i.e. Rows as Columns, Columns as Rows.

In what way I can do it?

Example :

```
1 4 7  
2 5 8  
3 6 9
```

as

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9
```

Comment: At least paste some HTML into jsfiddle.net so I can play with the code live. I was interested until I realized how boring the data setup would be. :P

Comment: A solution with only **css** can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094#16919439

Answer (score 46, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CsgK9/2/

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p><a href="#">Do it.</a></p>
```

js:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("table").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newrows = [];
        $this.find("tr").each(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                i++;
                if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                newrows[i].append($(this));
            });
        });
        $this.find("tr").remove();
        $.each(newrows, function(){
            $this.append(this);
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Support for `td` and `th` (mixed) would be great.

Comment: I tried editing to add support for th but my edit was rejected saying it should be in the form of a new answer, but I can't since the question is closed... Why again is it closed?? I think it shouldn't. Anyways here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/CsgK9/770/

Comment: Absolutely destroys complex tables (with `colgroup`s, `thead`s, `rowspan`s, etc.)

Comment: Actually this is not a straight `js`, but `jQuery`

Comment: @Jack I added `td` and `th` support (and ragged table support) in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308509/4582204

Answer (score 51):

There is this a CSS solution by David Bushell (using flexbox):
http://dbushell.com/2016/03/04/css-only-responsive-tables/

And there is also this CSS solution (using float)

```
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKnKL/3/

(they are both mentioned in this answer: [HTML Table with vertical rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918094/html-table-with-vertical-rows))

Comment: I really, really recommend the css solution. It will not add the js processing overload that is huge in some huge pages.

Comment: In the jsfiddle it looks wrong if you put a `<br />` in one cell (i.e. `<td>James<br />Bond</td>`). The same is true for Bushell's solution too.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Great!. You saved my lot of time.

Comment: FYI: The CSS solution does not work, if the table cells have different heights.

Answer (score 10):

This should work for arbitrary html:

```
function swap( cells, x, y ){
   if( x != y ){     
   var $cell1 = cells[y][x];
   var $cell2 = cells[x][y];
   $cell1.replaceWith( $cell2.clone() );
   $cell2.replaceWith( $cell1.clone() );
    }
}

var cells = [];
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
    var row = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
       row.push( $(this) );    
    });
    cells.push( row );
});

for( var y = 0; y <= cells.length/2; y++ ){
    for( var x = 0; x < cells[y].length; x++ ){
        swap( cells, x, y );
    }   
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hskke/1/

Comment: Also served me as an intro to jsfiddle, which I didn't know about. Thanks again!

Comment: Almost works for ragged tables (those with rows of unequal length).  Brilliantly simple!

Comment: @Reb Cabin I added ragged table support (and `td` and `th` support) in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308509/4582204

Answer (score 3):

What language do you want to do it in? I assume JavaScript, as you said jQuery. (jQuery is not a language, it's library to a language)

You need to find a way to represent the table as a data structure. This should be done via OOP for simplicity. I recommend you to get the number of columns and rows and put the data in 1 single, flat array.

You also need to design something that will parses through the HTML and gets the table, converting it to your structure, allowing computations to be done easily. This can be done via jQuery's method.

Then you need to find a sort function that sorts the flat array.

Lastly, you need to break up the the array into the appropriate columns and rows and rerender the HTML.

See! Not that difficult. Designing is pretty much done for you, all you need is to implement it. (Maybe i shouldn't do so much work for you..)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a non-jquery way of doing it and came up with this:

```js
const transposeTable = (tbody, newContainerType = "tbody") => {
  const rows = Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll("tr"))
  const newTbody = document.createElement(newContainerType)

  for (let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rows.length; rowIdx++) {
    const row = rows[rowIdx]
    const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("td, th"))

    for (let cellIdx = 0; cellIdx < cells.length; cellIdx++ ) {
      const cell = cells[cellIdx]
      const newRow = newTbody.children[cellIdx] || document.createElement("tr")
      if (!newTbody.children[cellIdx]) {
        newTbody.appendChild(newRow)
      }
      newRow.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true))
    }
  }
  
  // Do live DOM manipulations only once for performance
  tbody.parentElement.replaceChild(newTbody, tbody)
}

transposeTable(document.querySelector("tbody"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is @svinto answer with addition of

- Support for `td` and `th` (mixed)
- ragged tables (those with rows (and columns) of unequal length)

http://jsfiddle.net/xsp4eqwz/2/

```js
$("a#transposeButton").click(function(){
    $("table#transposeThis").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newrows = [];
        $this.find("tr").each(function(rowToColIndex){
            $(this).find("td, th").each(function(colToRowIndex){
                if(newrows[colToRowIndex] === undefined) { newrows[colToRowIndex] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                while(newrows[colToRowIndex].find("td, th").length < rowToColIndex){
                    newrows[colToRowIndex].append($("<td></td>"));
                }
                newrows[colToRowIndex].append($(this));
            });
        });
        $this.find("tr").remove();
        $.each(newrows, function(){
            $this.append(this);
        });
    });
    
    return false;
});
```

```css
td, th { padding:5px; border:1px solid #ccc;}

th { background-color: silver; font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<table id="transposeThis">
    <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
        <th>H3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
        <th>H3</th>
        <th>H4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p><a href="#" id="transposeButton">Do it.</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using simple HTML and CSS

```css
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
table{
    max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    table tr > *{
        display: block;
    }
    table tr {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
        <th>Head 5</th>
        <th>Head 6</th>
        <th>Head 7</th>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 5</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 6</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 7</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

[Edit in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reishabh/b2d9wc3L/3/)