# Change display of a table

Tags: javascript, java, html, html-table

With Javascript or java (in a webview), I wonder if it is possible to change the orientation of a table?

I need to display the columns in rows:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
     <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
     <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a Javascript function who could display one column under the other?

```
Jill

Smith

50
```

instead of

```
Jill Smith 50
```

I tried :

```javascript
window.document.getElementsByTagName('theTable')[0].style.display = "table-column";
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297591/how-to-invert-the-rows-and-columns-of-an-html-table

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was another way, like limit the width of the table, or the webview, so that the columns were displayed one under the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it with a simple way. I set the following on each of the columns, and now they are displayed like rows.

```
.style.position = 'fixed';
.style.top = '50px'; //next one 100px and so on
.style.left = '0px';
```