# How to rotate bootstrap-table (landscape view)?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table

I want to show my bootstrap-table by putting the columns headers on the left side and the row headers on the top.
I'm getting the data from JSON.
Any help? Thanks

Here is an idea of my code (JSON is hard coded just for testing the rotation of the table) :

```
<table id="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark" >
        <tr>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true" data-field="column1">COLUMN 1</th>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true" data-field="column2">COLUMN 2</th>
            <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true" data-field="column3">COLUMN 3</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
    var data = [
      {
        'column1': 'value1',
        'column2': 'value11',
        'column3': 'value12'
      },
      {
        'column1': 'value2',
        'column2': 'value21',
        'column3': 'value22'
      },
      {
        'column1': 'value3',
        'column2': 'value31',
        'column3': 'value32'
      },
      {
        'column1': 'value4',
        'column2': 'value41',
        'column3': 'value42'
      },
      {
        'column1': 'value5',
        'column2': 'value51',
        'column3': 'value52'
      },
      {
        'column1': 'value6',
        'column2': 'value61',
        'column3': 'value62'
      }
    ]
    $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
  })
</script>
```

Comment: please share the code you have tried, thanks :)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CsgK9/2/
Answer by svinto from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297591/how-to-invert-transpose-the-rows-and-columns-of-an-html-table

Comment: @KamilCiekalski yes this helped me thanks but the style of the column headers is not moving with them to the left. It remains on the top

Comment: Then i think you should add to table something like `class="inverse-table"` and rewrite it's style.

Comment: Hello, may this link help you: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS grid would be very good and clean solution.

For example:

```
grid-template-areas:
      "a b c"
      "d e f"
      "g h i";

@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    grid-template-areas:
            "c b a"
            "f e d"
            "i h g";
  }

@media (orientation: landscape) {
     grid-template-areas:
            "i h g"
            "f e d"
            "c b a";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, maybe it's useful for you as well.

```
<style>
  .bold {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<table id="table"></table>

<script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
    var originData = [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Item 0',
        'price': '$0',
        'title1': '1',
        'title2': '2',
        'title3': '3',
        'title4': '4',
        'title5': '5'
      }
    ]
    var data = []
        for (var key in originData[0]) {
      data.push({
        key: key,
        value: originData[0][key]
      })
    }

    $table.bootstrapTable({
      data: data,
      columns: [{
        field: 'key',
        title: 'Key',
        class: 'bold'
      }, {
        field: 'value',
        title: 'Value'
      }],
      showHeader: false
    })
  })
</script>
```