# I have a Table which is so wide to an A4 paper size and i want this Table to be vertical in HTML

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

I have a table like this

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |
| A3 | B3 |

I want it to be like this

| A header | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Another header | B1 | B2 |
| Another header | C1 | C2 |

I'm working with Thymeleaf, so if I use the normal way to write every line individually, it can't work because sometimes I have for 1 column more than a row, so I need a way to work with Thymeleaf conditions `<span th:text="${{ .....}}"></span>`

Comment: This sounds like a CSS question, not a Thymeleaf question.

Comment: See similar question: [How to invert (transpose) rows and columns of an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297591/how-to-invert-transpose-the-rows-and-columns-of-an-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the column width for the table

```html
<table border="solid">
  <tr>
    <th width="100">A header</th>
    <th width="150">Another header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but I edited the question, this doen't work in my situation because in this way I may have for every header 3 or for rows with the same header name

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used thymeleaf so I can't help you here.