# Convert a horizontal table into vertical with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to convert a horizontal table to a vertical one using only CSS?

**Here's what I have:**

| 1st header cell | 2nd header cell | 3rd header cell | 4th header cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st data cell | 2nd data cell | 3rd data cell | 4th data cell |

**Here's what I want:**

> **1st header cell** | 1st data cell
>
> **2nd header cell** | 2nd data cell
>
> **3rd header cell** | 3rd data cell
>
> **4th header cell** | 4th data cell

**My code:**

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1st header cell</th>
      <th>2nd header cell</th>
      <th>3rd header cell</th>
      <th>4th header cell</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1st data cell</td>
      <td>2nd data cell</td>
      <td>3rd data cell</td>
      <td>4th data cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use a table, use [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: I haven’t found a general way to do this with only CSS as so much of the structure is in the HTML. If you can’t find a CSS way, a way to do it at run time with a few lines of JS is here [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986623/i-want-to-change-the-table-from-a-horizontal-group-to-a-vertical-group/66994427#66994427

Answer (score 8):

Without changing your current code, you can shift the orientation of the table using this:

```
table {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

To adjust the centering of the table content, tweak the `align-items` and `justify-content` on the `table`.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any recommended CSS solutions for this, definitely not a "standard" one.

But there IS in fact at least one CSS workaround solution (with float):
http://jsfiddle.net/XKnKL/3/

```css
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1st header cell</th>
      <th>2nd header cell</th>
      <th>3rd header cell</th>
      <th>4th header cell</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1st data cell</td>
      <td>2nd data cell</td>
      <td>3rd data cell</td>
      <td>4th data cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm in a situation where I have to use a table, the HTML is a pre-set output of another process. Using this example I was able to convert my table into what I needed, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this, the table is structured so that each of the data columns are located next to the header cells (horizontally), and each of the columns are stacked vertically.

```
       <table>
           <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <td>data cell 1</td><td>data cell 2</td><td>data cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <td>data cell 1</td><td>data cell 2</td><td>data cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <td>data cell 1</td><td>data cell 2</td><td>data cell 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```